# How to do apply a shadeless material bump map

Tags: texturing, game-engine, normals

I applied a normal map to one of the object in my game, and because I am having some trouble with lighting, I was wondering if there was a way to have a shadeless material while still keeping the normal map effect.

Comment: **FOR ORIGINAL**: Use a Vector > Bump node **FOR EDIT:** No, this can not be done

Comment: You know, you might be able to [**bake your material to a texture**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tj-S5QAac3U) (really starts around 1:20), then enable shadeless. Let me know if this method appears to be what you are looking for.

Comment: NoviceInDisguise , Thanks for the help.  What I ended up doing was just turning up the "emit" setting in the materials panel, and it gave me the desired effect.  Thanks!

Comment: Go ahead and answer your own question then, so we can take this off of the unanswered list

Comment: Ok.  Sounds good.

Comment: To achieve this effect, I just turned up the "emit" setting in the materials panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this effect, I just turned up the "emit" setting in the materials panel.

[image: Illustration]